# Database problem: how to diagnose and fix the problem?

Tags: database, android, exception

I created an application which stores values into the database and retrieves the stored data. While running an application in run mode everything seems to work fine (the values are stored and retrieved successfully) but when I run in the debug mode the process throws IllegalStateException and so far haven't found a cause.

The method which retrieves an object Recording is the following:

```
public Recording getRecording(String filename) {

    Recording recording = null;
    String where = RECORDING_FILENAME + "='" + filename + "'";
    Log.v(TAG, "retrieving recording: filename = " + filename);

    try {
        cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_RECORDINGS, new String[]{RECORDING_FILENAME, RECORDING_TITLE, RECORDING_TAGS, RECORDING_PRIVACY_LEVEL, RECORDING_LOCATION, RECORDING_GEO_TAGS, RECORDING_GEO_TAGGING_ENABLED, RECORDING_TIME_SECONDS, RECORDING_SELECTED_COMMUNITY}, where, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //String filename = c.getString(0);
            String title = cursor.getString(1);
            String tags = cursor.getString(2);
            int privacyLevel = cursor.getInt(3);
            String location = cursor.getString(4);
            String geoTags = cursor.getString(5);
            int iGeoTaggingEnabled = cursor.getInt(6);
            String recordingTime = cursor.getString(7);
            String communityID = cursor.getString(8);
            cursor.close();
            recording = new Recording(filename, title, tags, privacyLevel, location, geoTags, iGeoTaggingEnabled, recordingTime, communityID);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
        Log.w(TAG, msg);
        recording = null;
    }
    return recording;
}
```

and it is called from another class (Settings):

```
private Recording getRecording(String filename) {
    dbAdapter = dbAdapter.open();
    Recording recording = dbAdapter.getRecording(filename);
    dbAdapter.close();
    return recording;
}
```

While running through the code above everything works fine but then I notice an exception in another thread:
[alt text http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/862/illegalstateexception.jpg](http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/862/illegalstateexception.jpg)

and don't know neither what is the possible cause of this exception nor how to debug the code from that thread to diagnose the cause.

I would be very thankful if anyone knew what is the possible issue here.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of the exception? Or at least, the relevant bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that `cursor.close()` is inside an "`if`" - that's when `SQLiteCursor.finalize()` will throw an IllegalStateException (I googled for it). You migh be getting an empty recordset, for instance, if some other process/thread didn't have the time to commit.

Close it always, even if it's result set is empty.

I'd also advice you to access fields by names, not indices, for future compatibility. And do both `close()`s in `finally{}` blocks.